# Connecting SQL Server 2012 with out part of the sql installed on the client

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have 4 pc's. 2 have full setup SQ Server 2012 setup, 1 as all but the data base setup, and 1 does not have SQL setup at all. The 3 with SQL setup connects to the one I call the subserver that has the data base setup on. The one without SQL installed on it at all does not connect throws an exception. 
Here is my connection string.

Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security="";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;password=Xxxx1234;OLE DB Services=-2;Initial Catalog=score_data;Data Source=192.168.9.25,1433;Initial File Name="";Packet Size=4096;Auto Translate=True;Server SPN="";

Here is my Delphi code used to create this string and connect

```
function TFrmTb2.ConnectToSqlDB(Var DataBase : TADOConnection; Catalog : String; Var Msg : ShortString) : Boolean;
  var
    cntStr     : String;
  begin
    msg := '';
    CntStr := DataBase.Name;
    if not DataBase.Connected then
      begin
        if Not DataBase.Connected then
          begin
            with FrmTb2 do
              begin  //Edit ConfigHdwe2016Nw.Ini in tne Score2016NW Directory section SQL
                CntStr := 'Provider='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Provider')+';';//SQLNCLI11.1';//SQLNCLI10.1;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Integrated Security='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Integrated Security')+';';//"";';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Persist Security Info='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Persist Security Info')+';';//False;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'User ID='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','User ID')+';';//shithead;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'password='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','password')+';';//shithead;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'OLE DB Services='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','OLE DB Services')+';';// -2;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Initial Catalog='+Catalog+';';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Data Source='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Data Source')+';';//\SQLEXPRESS;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Initial File Name='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Initial File Name')+';';//"";';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Packet Size='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Packet Size')+';';//4096;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Auto Translate='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Auto Translate')+';';//True;';
                CntStr := CntStr + 'Server SPN='+ReadIniStr(IniHdwe,'SQL','Server SPN')+';';//""';
              end;
//            ShowMessage(CntStr);
            DataBase.ConnectionString := CntStr;
            try
              DataBase.Connected := True;
              if DataBase.Connected then
                begin
//                  ShowMessage('After Conection');
                  result := True;
                end
              else
                begin
                  result := False;
                  ShowMessage('Unable to Connect to Score2016Nw Database Bad Ip or Connection Missing1');
                end;
            except
              result := False;
              ShowMessage('Unable to Connect to Score2016Nw Database Bad Ip or Connection Missing2');
            end;
          end
        else
         result := True;
      end
    else
      result := True; // we are still conected to the sql database
  end;
```

My network person tells me that the fire fall port 1433 is open ( it is a hardware wirewall and I don't have access). I have checked and rechecked that on the subserver that the ip2 is Active = Yes; Enabled = Yes; IP Address = 255.255.255.0 (Sub net Mask); TCP Port = 1433 and IPALL Dynamic Ports = ''(Blank) and TCP Port = 1433. I have read just about every post I can find and nothing short of Installing SQL Server Express 2012 on the clients will make it work to talk to the subserver and connect to the database. Is there any tools I could use to find the problem or am I going to need to Install SQL Server on all clients (what a pain)

Comment: When you say "Throws an exception", you really need to tell us what that exception is. I'm guessing that it's telling you it could not find the provider.

Comment: ShowMessage('Unable to Connect to Score2016Nw Database Bad Ip or Connection Missing2');
as in my code.

Comment: That is a custom error message generated by your own code, which is of no help to us. You are catching the exception, why don't you read the exception's message and report what it says to us? In any case, it is impossible for us to replicate your exact error with what you've provided in your question, other than the provider which is not installed, as I describe in my answer.

Comment: Instead of guessing, refer to the actual exception. I almost sure you will find out the real reason yourself once you do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string includes `SQLNCLI11` as its provider. This means, you need to install [SQL Native Client 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280510.aspx) on this machine, as that's the provider it's looking for. When you install SQL Server, it also installs SQL Native Client for you by default. But on a machine which SQL has never been installed on, you will have to install it yourself.

Or, as an alternative, you could use the OLE DB drivers which come pre-installed in Windows, by using `SQLOLEDB.1` for the provider instead.

Comment: That was it down loaded and installed the SQLNCLI11 Driver and all works. The problem with SQLOLEDB1 is it has problems with DateTime and translating them from SQL

Comment: @Sbossen Interesting, our company has been using SQL OLE DB drivers for over 10 years and do a **LOT** of work with DateTime fields. What problem do you mean?

Comment: When I read a datetime from sql using a ado connection  I would get an invalid format for a DateTime when I switched back to a  SQLNCLI11 no problem. and if you can find is the documentation from MS says when the driver was up dated and the problem was in datetime (See Link above for Installing Sql Native Client 11 I look a round a lot to find the install MSI). I am using Delphi XE6